# SMB share in-accessible from any PC, mac, android

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders, smb

I used to share directories from Ubuntu 12 to all other PCs on network, but since I clean-installed  Ubuntu 13.1, shares are created and visible but they are in-accessible form the other machines

[image]

When I access this from OS X using password, authentication fails.

[image]

When I login with guest user I get share listing:

[image]

But I cannot access any of them:

[image]

Problem is consistent when I access the share across OS X, windows and Android. How do I debug it?

Here's smb.log

> [2013/11/03 00:39:19.206526,  0]
>   param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
>   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/fxshare
>   failed. Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it.
It comes from the fact that the samba users must be declared with :

```
sudo smbpasswd -a fx
```

(replace fx with any user you would like to allow)